# What is the most concise way to insert or update a line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I write a lot of adhoc scripts for adding lines to sudoers, sysctl.conf etc.  Usually I use the lineinfile ansible module. Sometimes, however, I don't get to do that so I use :

```
WHAT_I_WANT='my line of text = something'
WHAT_TO_REPLACE='my line of text = .*'
FILE_TO_EDIT=conf_file.conf
if ( ! grep -q "^$WHAT_I_WANT\$" FILE_TO_EDIT ); then
    echo  "$WHAT_I_WANT" >> FILE_TO_EDIT
else
    sed -i "s/$WHAT_TO_REPLACE/$WHAT_I_WANT/g' FILE_TO_EDIT
fi
```

My guess is there's a more efficient way to do this. Ideally with one line and one language (and also in a way that allows regexp matching, removing commented out lines and backing up files)  But I don't know what that is.

Comment: Well, typing a  longer text three times seems inefficient and error prone  to me. Use a var.

Comment: @lot can't argue with that, but not exactly the point to the question!

Comment: You just maybe want to add /g global flag to the `sed` command if you want to change every occurrence of that text. Sorry for posting but I don't have yet enough of the points to comment.

Comment: Yeah, I can (and probably would) do that. I don't just want to change every occurrence of the text, I also want to add it to the file if it doesn't already exist.  Also, it's better that you answer in an answer than in the comments, even if it is a short answer.

Comment: @PeterTurner true, but this isn't really an answer s a comment would indeed be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Not actually a one-liner, but you could do this with one invocation of `sed`:

```
sed -e '
   /pat/{s//repl/g;h;}
   $!b
   G
   s/\n..*//;t
   s/$/repl/
' yourfile
```

N.B.: I've deliberateley used `pat` and `repl` for pattern and replacement respectively, and not the shell variables as you've done. Basically for 2 main reasons, they would get in the way of the sed code flow + for correctness we need to quote both, and differently at that, to make them work. That job I leave it to you.

Flow: Say, the file never had a /pat/ then all lines are taken to stdout by the $!b command and the last line when appended by G just sees an empty hold
so the `t` is not taken and we have an append operation.

When we see a /pat/ line, then it is s///-ed and hold area is marked. if it's not the last line, we simply break out to stdout. For eof, we do a check of hold and since it's non-empty(assuming `repl` is `NONEMPTY`, the test path would be taken after removing the hold from the pattern space.

---

`Perl` affords the clarity to match the intent word-for-word in the code:

```
perl -lne '$a += s/pat/repl/g,print}{print q[repl] unless $a'
```

To be read as: The variable `$a` serves as the counter for the number of substitutions. At the end, we would append to file when no subs were made earlier.

And as for supplying the pattern/replacement info via variables, we can do it:

```
WHAT_I_WANT='my line of text = something'
WHAT_TO_REPLACE='my line of text = .*'
FILE_TO_EDIT=conf_file.conf

perl -li -sn -e '
        $a += s/$pat/$repl/g,print}{print $repl unless $a
' -- -pat="$WHAT_I_WANT" -repl="$WHAT_TO_REPLACE" -- "$FILE_TO_EDIT"
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using extra long variable names to replace long strings is IMO
  counterproductive.
- To have variables be expanded in grep/sed commands use double quotes.
- Using wildcards `.*` in variable asignments will [carry out filename expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)(globbing)
- The following script uses conditional execution on success `&&` or fail `||` instead of an if.

---

```
REPL='something'
PATT='my line of text = '
FILE=conf_file.conf

cat $FILE
echo '========='

grep -q "^$PATT" $FILE && (sed -i "s/^$PATT.*$/$PATT$REPL/" $FILE) || (echo "$PATT$REPL" >> $FILE)

cat $FILE
```

Comment: OP needs to match some regex which means using regex quantifiers like `*`  - using those chars in variable assignments does **not** carry out filename expansion and as long as you quote your vars that should not be a problem. Run `var=*` and then compare the output of `echo $var` and `echo "$var"`.

Comment: @don_crissti How do you expand the vars conataining REs in sed/grep commands and at the same time escape from globbing?

Comment: As I said, you quote your vars... I don't see what's so unclear...

Comment: It's not my problem, I just pointed out what was wrong with OPs approach.